# Write into text file located in Dropbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling for two days to write into a text file using Javascript. 
The text file is located on the Dropbox. 
My code:

```js
try
{
    var txtFile = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/...../MyFile.txt";
    var file = new File(txtFile);
    var str = "My string of text";

    file.open("w"); // open file with write access
    file.write(str);
    file.close();
}
catch(ex)
{
    alert(err.message);
}
```

But does not write anything into the text file. Any idea how can I solve this problem? or is it a deadend?

Comment: This is not possible, you don't have write access to files on DropBox with simple http GET.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) does not write anything into the text file. Any idea how can I solve this problem? or is it a deadend?

You have to use the official dropbox API for this purpose:

```
Method: PUT or POST 
Url: https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/<path>?param=val
Body: { file contents }
```

Dropbox also provides a client library, [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) that is linked from the official Dropbox [JavaScript developer page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/javascript). With that you can write code like this ([copied from the dropbox.js tutorial](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/getting_started.md#write-a-file)):

```
client.writeFile("hello_world.txt", "Hello, world!\n", function(error, stat) {
  if (error) {
    return showError(error);  // Something went wrong.
  }

  alert("File saved as revision " + stat.versionTag);
});
```

Note that there is an [upcoming V2 of the API](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/) and a new JavaScript library is said to be *available soon*.